# How do I properly format by output variables so that they align with their title? For example Last name, first name in users, etc

Tags: java

Here's my code, it's at the bottom that I don't know what to do to format it properly, I tried using printf but it keeps giving me errors whenever I try to reformat it and it doesn't want to go through, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get the users' first and last name under "users", their balance under "balance and etc?

```
package mybalances;

import java.util.Scanner;
import static oracle.jrockit.jfr.events.Bits.doubleValue;

/**
 *
 * @author carroyo108
 */
    public class MyBalances {

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 //first user
  System.out.print("Enter user 1 first name:");
  String firstFirst = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("Enter user 1 last name: ");
  String firstLast = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 1, Account 1 Name: ");
  String firstaccountOne = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 1, Account 1 Balance: ");
  double firstbalanceOne = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("User 1, Account 2 Name: ");
  String firstaccountTwo = keyboard.nextLine();

  keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 1, Account 2 Balance: ");
  double firstbalanceTwo = keyboard.nextDouble();

  keyboard.nextLine(); 
  System.out.print("\n");

 System.out.print("User 2 First Name: ");
  String secondFirst = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 2 Last Name: ");
  String secondLast = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 2, Account 1 Name: ");
  String secondaccountOne = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 2 Account 1 Balance: ");
  double secondbalanceOne = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("User 2, Account 2 Name: ");
  String secondaccountTwo = keyboard.nextLine();

  keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 2, Account 2 Balance: ");
  double secondbalanceTwo = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("\n");
  //Third user inputs
  System.out.print("User 3 First Name: ");
 String thirdFirst = keyboard.nextLine();

 keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.print("User 3 Last Name: ");
String thirdLast = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 3, Account 1 Name: ");
  String thirdaccountOne = keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 3, Account 1 Balance: ");
  double thirdbalanceOne = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("User 3, Account 2 Name: ");
  String thirdaccountTwo = keyboard.nextLine();

  keyboard.nextLine();

  System.out.print("User 3, Account 2 Balance: ");
  double thirdbalanceTwo = keyboard.nextDouble();

  keyboard.nextLine();
  System.out.print("\n");

 double firstusertotalCost = ((firstbalanceOne + firstbalanceTwo) / 2);
 double secondusertotalCost = ((secondbalanceTwo + secondbalanceTwo) / 2);
 double thirdusertotalCost = ((thirdbalanceTwo + thirdbalanceTwo) / 2);

 System.out.printf("Users" + "       " + "Account"  + "      " + "Balance" + "     " + "Account" + "     " + "Balance" + "   " + "Average" + "    " + "Status\n");

 System.out.printf(("%5d",10) + firstLast,firstFirst);

   }
}
```

Comment: Start by creating an **Account** class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation by overloading the '+' operator

```
System.out.print("Users" + firstFirst + " " + firstLast + " Account " + firstaccountOne);
```

Your code shows very poor practices as there is a lot of repeating code. I would suggest using a loop condition (while/for loop) and try store your inputs from the user in a data structure like an array.

Comment: we.re not allowed to use loops or arrays and i tried using printf("%-15s %10s %n", firstLast firstFirst); but it gave me an error

Comment: If you want to just print the user name `System.out.print(firstLast + firstFirst)` if you want to add in a space `System.out.print(firstLast + " " + firstFirst)`